Socket Timeout will kill the Thread in Python
I am going to use the following Python program in my dedicated online server. My doubt is for each and every new connection to server, it is creating a new thread number. I already set the timeout function for the child. It is working fine, but the thread number keeps on increasing. I thought the thread is not clearing properly. Kindly give me the solution to clear or kill the thread process completely.
import socket
from threading import Thread

def on_new_client(client_socket, addr):
while True:
    client_socket.settimeout(10)
    data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    client_socket.settimeout(None)
    send="GOK"
    client_socket.send(send.encode())

    if not data:
        print('Disconnected')
        break
    print("Adr and data",addr,data)
client_socket.close()


def main():
host = '127.0.0.1'  # allow any incoming connections
port = 4001

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))  # bind the socket to the port and ip address
s.listen(5)  # wait for new connections

while True:
    c,addr=s.accept()  # Establish connection with client.
    print("New connection from:",addr)
    thread = Thread(target=on_new_client, args=(c, addr))  # create the thread
    thread.start()  # start the thread
c.close() #c.close()
thread.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()


Your concern is that the threads created for each new client connection are not being cleared properly, which leads to a growing number of threads. To address this, there are two potential causes:

The thread isn't terminating: If the client doesn't disconnect or the on_new_client function gets stuck, the thread might stay alive.

The threads are not being cleaned up: After the thread finishes its
work, it may not be properly joined or cleared.


You can ensure that threads are properly terminated by:

Using the threading module more carefully.
Making sure threads are joined after they finish.
Handling client socket disconnections and timeouts correctly.
Setting the "daemon" attribute for threads if they are meant to
terminate when the main program finishes.

Improved version of your code:
import socket
from threading import Thread

def on_new_client(client_socket, addr):
    try:
        while True:
            client_socket.settimeout(10)
            data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            client_socket.settimeout(None)
            
            if not data:
                print(f'Client {addr} disconnected')
                break
            
            send = "GOK"
            client_socket.send(send.encode())
            print(f"Address: {addr}, Data: {data}")
    
    except socket.timeout:
        print(f"Connection timed out for {addr}")
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error with client {addr}: {e}")
    
    finally:
        client_socket.close()
        print(f"Connection closed for {addr}")

def main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 4001

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    
    print(f"Server started on {host}:{port}")
    
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = s.accept()
        print(f"New connection from: {addr}")
        
        thread = Thread(target=on_new_client, args=(client_socket, addr), daemon=True)  # Mark thread as daemon
        thread.start()  # Start the thread

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Next Step:
Add detailed logging for thread and connection status. b. Test the server with multiple connections to verify threads clean up as expected.
